# Remove 'keywords' and 'site section' from showing on front page links

Tags: drupal

I have a [Drupal 7 installation](http://jeetworks.org/) that shows the default front page. Published pages/nodes show up with the title, teaser text, and a list of keywords as well as the site-section under which they are categorized using the Taxonomy module.

I would like to limit the listing to only show the title and teaser, and not the site-section and keywords. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. You have to go to:

```
 Administration » Structure » Content types » Story » Manage display
```

click on "Teaser", and choose to hide the appropriate bits.